# Bullet and alignment issue in itemize environment

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, itemize, bullets

Itemize environment under the macro is not showing bullet. It's showing dash. Also, there is an issue with horizontal alignment. It's not aligned properly. I already fixed with by using `\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$, leftmargin=*]`. But I would like to know why it is happening? Thanks in advanced for all the help.

Here is my current result: [image]

Here is my MWE that producing this result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0.9in]}{%
\end{itemize}
}
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{%
\item[#1]
\textbf{#2}%
\hfill%
{\footnotesize #3}%
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{entrylist}
 \entry
  {05/15 - 01/16}
  {Position 1}
  {Employer 1}
   \begin{itemize}%[label=$\bullet$, leftmargin=*]
    \item Task 1 
    \item Task 2 
    \item Task 3
    \item Task 4
   \end{itemize}  
 \end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `entrylist` makes a first level `itemize`, so the inner one is second level.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved by comments